# xaml ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters reference

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<Window.Resources>      
    <utl:Connection x:Key="myconfig">
        <utl:Connection.HostNameIP>localhost</utl:Connection.HostNameIP>
    </utl:Connection>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="mysession" 
        ObjectType="{x:Type utl:Session}" MethodName="OpenSession">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <ObjectDataProvider ObjectInstance="{StaticResource myconfig}" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>           
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
```

This is not working.
How do I use myconfig as a MethodParameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="mysession" ObjectType="{x:Type utl:Session}" MethodName="OpenSession">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="myconfig" />
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

It should work provided that the `OpenSession` method accepts a `Connection`:

```
public class Session
{
    public void OpenSession(Connection connection)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. I am still learning wpf. Everything is still confusing to me. haha.